# How do I acquire the full armour of thorns set?

Tags: dark-souls

I've been looking around the world for ages to bump into the guy who uses the armour of thorns (Kirk, Knight of Thorns). I know I have to be in human form and that he appears before certain bosses. Still, I've only ever been able to acquire the sword and shields of this armour. How do I get the rest of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You meet Kirk up to 3 times per playthrough. 1st in the Depths, then in the Demon Ruins, and finally in Lost Izalith. You need to fight him in this order otherwise he will not appear. You must be alive and have not beaten the boss of the area for him to invade.

Each time you fight him, there is a chance he drops either his sword or shield (both are uncommon drops)

After you kill him the third time (in Lost Izalith), his corpse will appear in the Queelag Domain (past the bonfire where the Daughter of Chaos resides). The rest of the armor set is contains on this corpse.

more info:

http://darksouls.wikidot.com/armor-of-thorns 
http://darksouls.wikidot.com/kirk-knight-of-thorns